# How to add a library to python permamently?

Tags: python, matplotlib, package

I am using Pycharm for coding. At a specific project, I used setting/Project/Project interpreter to install some packages like Numpy and Matplotlib (by + button and search). But when I opened a new project in pycharm, none of the installed packages were in the new project. What can I do to the packages add to al new projects automatically?

Comment: You may use virtual environment for project.

To install packages permanently in python use pip command in terminal

`pip install package_name`

Answer (score 0):

Pycharm stores the modules for each project in a Virtual Environment (you probalby have a `venv` folder in your projects). So there are two main things that you can do:

- Install your packages with `pip install <package>` on your terminal and disable `venv`. See [this post's answer](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003445839-Stop-setting-up-projects-as-virtual-environments-in-PyCharm).
- Re-use the `venv` from previous projects. by selecting `Existing Environment` on your project's configuration. See this [Pycharm doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html#).